# How to explain lack of 3 year Income Tax Return acknowledgement or Form 16A that is required?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, india, schengen-visas

I will be applying for a Schengen Visa in VFS Italy, and according to their [website](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/mumbai/pdf/Tourist-Visa-Application-Arrangement.pdf), we need to show Income Tax Return (ITR) acknowledgements or [Form 16A](https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/tax-services/form-16A-download-deductor.aspx) of last 3 assessment years.

However, I only have Form 16A and ITR acknowledgement of 1 assessment year, as I was under the tax paying bracket before that, which means, I did not have to pay taxes, and therefore, didn't get a Form 16 from my employers and didn't file an ITR.

So, where and how can I explain this to the consulate? Will this be a problem?

Comment: Do you have payslips for the said period?

Comment: @RedBaron Not the full period, I have for about 15 months out of about 20 months for which I didn't have to pay tax.

Comment: Is that a continuous 15 months? If there's a gap, were  you with the same employer over the time?

Comment: @CSM There's a 2 months gap in between, and I have been with two employers over the 15 month time period.